# Unsetting a $_SESSION with references

Tags: php, session, unset

I am trying to unset a session from `$_SESSION` with the following function:

```
public function unsetSession($s) {

        if (is_array($s)) {
    
            $temp = &$_SESSION;
                            
            foreach ($s as $value) {

                if (isset($temp[$value])) {

                    $temp = &$temp[$value];

                }
                else {

                    return false;

                }
                
            }

            unset($temp);

            return true;

        }

}
```

I call it like this `unsetSession(array("key1", "key2", "etc."));`.

However, it doesn't work and the session will not be deleted. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why trying to do it by reference? Just go straight for `$_SESSION`.

Comment: `unset($temp);` this only unsets the reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php "_When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable content will be destroyed._"

Comment: References are not pointers and do not function as such. They are unnecessary in your code, just `unset($_SESSION[$value])`.

Comment: I also don't understand the relationship between looping over keys to unset, returning early if there's something not set, then only un-setting the last item it finds outside of the loop? If you were trying to unset multiple session variables by an array this function could be a lot simpler.

Comment: I just want to unset when the very keys provided in the array `$s` are found. I cannot simply unset the `$value` because I don't have it available. If I have set `$_SESSION['key']['key2']['key3']`, I want to be able to only delete `key3`.